# How can I add more server type options to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-neon

I'm following a Spring tutorial that uses Apache Tomcat and Eclipse, but when I try to add a server I don't see Tomcat in the options. (See pic below)

What can I do to add it there?

I use Eclipse Neon release (4.6.1)

[image: Picture of New Server wizard of Eclips that doesn't include Apache Tomcat options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Help > Install New Software

Search for your required server or if you have link to it, add it in 'Work with' tab